# Is there a way to emulate a memcpy to store value to a redis key?

Tags: redis, memcpy, hiredis

I have a data buffer that I would want to set/store into a redis DB to be reused/get by downstream modules. I have a pointer to the data buffer and I would want to emulate some kind of memcpy directly from the buffer pointer into the redis key value and I know the exact length of the data I want to copy.

I can do this in 2 stages

1) Fwrite the buffer into a file say buffer.bin for the size data length
2) Simulate 'redis-cli -x set buffer1

I confirmed I can get the file contents back with 
redis-cli -x get buffer1 > /home/buffer-copy.bin

But I would want to avoid additional file operation which I see as completely redundant/costly operation if I can save from my memory pointer directly into the redis key-value. Can you please share your thoughts on how I can do this?

Edit: trying to use "C" hiredis interfaces to access redis

Comment: I presume this is C++?

Comment: No, I would need to use a C client like a hiredis and I am trying to include call the hiredis client routines to achieve this objective, I did not see a way how I can get a "redis-cli -x" type functionality with hiredis and hence this query.